# Timestamp roundtrip from Spark Python to Pandas and back

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, timestamp

How do you do a roundtrip conversion of timestamp data from Spark Python to Pandas and back? I read data from a Hive table in Spark, want to do some calculations in Pandas, and write the results back to Hive. Only the last part is failing, converting a Pandas timestamp back to a Spark DataFrame timestamp.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dates = [
    ('today', '2017-03-03 11:30:00')
  , ('tomorrow', '2017-03-04 08:00:00')
  , ('next Thursday', '2017-03-09 20:00:00')
]
string_date_rdd = sc.parallelize(dates)
timestamp_date_rdd = string_date_rdd.map(lambda t: (t[0], datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))
timestamp_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(timestamp_date_rdd, ['Day', 'Date'])
timestamp_pandas_df = timestamp_df.toPandas()
roundtrip_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(timestamp_pandas_df)
roundtrip_df.printSchema()
roundtrip_df.show()

root
 |-- Day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: long (nullable = true)

+-------------+-------------------+
|          Day|               Date|
+-------------+-------------------+
|        today|1488540600000000000|
|     tomorrow|1488614400000000000|
|next Thursday|1489089600000000000|
+-------------+-------------------+
```

At this point the roundtrip Spark DataFrame has the date column as datatype `long`. In Pyspark this can be converted back to a datetime object easily, e.g., `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(148908960000000000 / 1000000000)`, although the time of day is off by a few hours. How do I do this to convert the data type of the Spark DataFrame?

Python 3.4.5, Spark 1.6.0

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution I found:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
extra_column_df = roundtrip_df.select(roundtrip_df.Day, roundtrip_df.Date).withColumn('new_date', roundtrip_df.Date / 1000000000)
roundtrip_timestamp_df = extra_column_df.select(extra_column_df.Day, extra_column_df.new_date.cast(TimestampType()).alias('Date')
```

Outputs:

```
root
 |-- Day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: timestamp (nullable = true)

+-------------+--------------------+
|        Day  |                Date|
+-------------+--------------------+
|        today|2017-03-03 11:30:...|
|     tomorrow|2017-03-04 08:00:...|
|next Thursday|2017-03-09 20:00:...|
+-------------+--------------------+
```

As an additional bug or feature, this seems to convert all the dates to UTC, including DST awareness.

Answer (score 1):

Converting the datetime64 columns to python datetime objects works for me.

```
from pandas import Series

def convert_to_python_datetime(df):
    df_copy = df.copy()
    for column_name, column in df_copy.iteritems():
        if column.dtype.kind == 'M':
            df_copy[column_name] = Series(column.dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype=object)
    return df_copy


tmp = convert_to_python_datetime(timestamp_pandas_df)
roundtrip_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(tmp)
roundtrip_df.printSchema()
roundtrip_df.show()
```

Outputs:

```
 root
 |-- Day: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: timestamp (nullable = true)

+-------------+--------------------+
|          Day|                Date|
+-------------+--------------------+
|        today|2017-03-03 11:30:...|
|     tomorrow|2017-03-04 08:00:...|
|next Thursday|2017-03-09 20:00:...|
+-------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: When I tried this roundtrip_df.Date column's datatype came back as 'struct' instead of 'timestamp'.

Comment: What version Pandas are you using?

Comment: 0.19.1, according to pd.__version__

Comment: Okay, the example has been edited and now works with pandas 0.19. The key change was "Series(column.dt.to_pydatetime(), dtype=object)". Pandas normally converts arrays of datetime to Timestamp. Series(x, dtype=object) prevents that.